# How do I get a dashboard like the one drupal.org is using?

Tags: 7, dashboard

In search of making the dashboard for the user like drupal.org site I came to know there is a dashboard module in the drupal core. It is already enabled but I am not getting user interface like drupal.org site, not for admin and not for otehr users, How can I activate that so the user profile looks like what is on drupal.org site. I enabled the permission for user also. And where is the tab for the dashboard or how to enable it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Combine [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with [Panels.](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). Don't; know what is used on Drupal.org, but Panels will get you there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dashboard on drupal.org is made using [Homebox](https://drupal.org/project/homebox) module.

> Homebox allows site administrators to create dashboards for their users, using blocks as widgets. Blocks in a Homebox page are resizeable, and reorderable by dragging.

Comment: Hmmm, yes that is true, it is made using the Homebox, later while doing search I  came to know that while reading that module's description. I tries also, and came to know it works as place holder only for blocks, various blocks we need to make using Views. Hence it does not provide predefined blocks with target of user profile, or user activity. Thanks for information though.